# visjs network arrow customization

Tags: vis.js-network, vis.js

I need to show "?" instead of the standard arrows types in my visjs network.

I followed this solution:
[How to change arrows in vis.js to chicken feet or cardinality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35581834/how-to-change-arrows-in-vis-js-to-chicken-feet-or-cardinality)

However I also need to hide and show nodes based on a property on it. Once the nodes are hidden and shown again,  the "?" on edges is lost and the edges default to the standard arrow heads.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gu2kwze0/51/

```
network.getEdgeById('1').drawArrows = function drawArrows(ctx, arrowData) {
    ctx.font = "20px OpenSans";  

  if (this.options.arrows.to.enabled === true) {
        //'to' side suspect
        ctx.fillText('?', arrowData.to.point.x, arrowData.to.point.y);
  }
  if (this.options.arrows.from.enabled === true) {
          //only 'from' side suspect
    ctx.fillText(' ? ', arrowData.from.point.x, arrowData.from.point.y);

  }
  }
```

Click in the network to hide & then show the edges. 
What could be wrong?